# posix_ipc python package equivalent for Windows?

Tags: python, ipc

Inter process communication primitives (Semaphores, Shared Memory) in python on windows? posix_ipc works great on linux, anything similar for windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use most (all) of the [win32 ipc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx) when you install [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

Answer (score 0):

For semaphores on Windows I've created https://pypi.org/project/semaphore-win-ctypes/.

This provides low level access to the Windows Semaphore APIs from python. There's some interesting use cases this enables like letting python processes and non-python processes acquire the same semaphore object.